# dplyr: include all elements in filter list, even if not in data set

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, tidyverse

```
df1

Row   Taste       Quantity
#1    Vanilla         3
#2    Chocolate       1
#3    Strawberry      6
```

I would like to filter the list and include a c(list) that has more flavors. But if the flavors in the list dont exist in the Taste column I would like to add a new row.

```
df1 %>% filter(Taste %in% c("Chocolate", "Strawberry", "Banana"))
```

but this only returns the chocolate and strawberry rows. I would like it to return:

```
Row   Taste       Quantity
#2    Chocolate       1
#3    Strawberry      6
#4    Banana          0 (or could be NA)
```

Is there a way to append the items in the list to the results even if the data doesn't exist in df1?

Comment: You cannot `filter` something that doesn't exist :) You'll probably need to `join` on the flavours you want to have, so anything else will be ignored.

Comment: You will need to rbind the rows you want added

Comment: @SmitM Good thought, but they don't have the full rows they want to add, only the tastes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# example data frame
df = read.table(text = "
Row   Taste       Quantity
1    Vanilla         3
2    Chocolate       1
3    Strawberry      6
", header=T)

# vector of tastes to have in output
taste_vector = c("Chocolate", "Strawberry", "Banana")

library(dplyr)

data.frame(taste_vector) %>%                         # start with the vector of tastes you want to have
  left_join(df, by=c("taste_vector"="Taste")) %>%    # join original data to see what was found and what wasn't
  mutate(Row = ifelse(is.na(Row), max(Row, na.rm = T) + cumsum(is.na(Row)), Row))  # update Row column

#   taste_vector Row Quantity
# 1    Chocolate   2        1
# 2   Strawberry   3        6
# 3       Banana   4       NA
```

You can add `mutate(Quantity = coalesce(Quantity, 0L))` if you don't want `NA`s in your `Quantity` column.

Comment: Ahh that makes perfect sense. Didn't even think about joining the two. It's working now, thanks to you! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Using tidyverse (dplyr, forcats and tidyr)

First create a filter object (filter_vals) of the variables you want to filter on. In a mutate (assuming the variable is not a factor), we mutate Taste into a factor and expand the factor levels with values from the filter object. Next we use complete to expand the values in the data.frame with the missing levels that are in the factor and set empty values to 0. Finally filter the data.frame with the filter object.

```
library(tidyverse)

filter_vals <- c("Chocolate", "Strawberry", "Banana")

df1 %>% 
  mutate(Taste = as_factor(Taste),
         Taste = fct_expand(Taste, filter_vals)) %>%   
  complete(Taste, fill = list(Quantity = 0))
  filter(Taste %in% filter_vals) 

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  Taste      Quantity
  <fct>         <dbl>
1 Chocolate         1
2 Strawberry        6
3 Banana            0
```